# Website doesn't behave properly offline

Tags: javascript, html, ajaxify

***Hi everyone,***

I have basic knowledge of html. I have been inspecting the design of a website: http://www.merixstudio.com/

I have saved the website to my desktop to examine. When I navigate the website, it won't load the pages, but it shows the site's loading icon in the centre of the screen.

This site is html5 coded and uses PushState ajaxify.

If someone could give me a quick runaround of how these functions work and why the don't work offline I would be very greatful.

**Thanks for reading and for your time.**

Comment: you are basically connecting to the webserver via internet when you are browsing online. all of the images and related stuff will be on the server which get downloaded when you access a page. when you are offline how do you expect this. you will have to get all these images locally for you to work on your system

Comment: It's like locking your wife in the house, then wondering why she didn't go shopping. You abusive, offline-inflicting person, you! :P Seriously now, if you want to make an offline webapp work, you need to make a manifest. Withoout a manifest, the website can't know what files it should contain ahead of time. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)'s a tutorial.

Comment: I have saved the website complete, and even if images were to be missing, shouldn't the pages still load?

-Amadan Hahaha I get you, sorry just bear with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of all JS, css and image file are on live you have to set to as local folder by updating src in script tag in head tag and also need to update href attr in link tag in head tag.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I think I know what I have to do!

Comment: Says 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'!